# Error in combining plots

Tags: plotting

I have two plots I1 and I2 for two different lines perpendicular to each other. When I combine these graphs they do not perpendicular to each other.

```
I1 = Plot[{-4 (x - 1) + 13}, {x, -1, 3}];  
I2 = Plot[{(x - 1)/4 + 13}, {x, -1, 3}];
Show[I1,I2]
```

Comment: mathematica 11.1, but I also checked in MA 10,  it was giving same result.

Comment: This is do to the rescaling to the axis of the fist graph, this is the default behaviour. i.e., not an error but a feature

Comment: @Ruud3.1415 I understand this is due to scaling different .  Actually my two lines are perpendicular to each other . I want to show this in plot but due to scaling problem these are not perpendicular to each other

Comment: you do know that you can plot two lines at the same time?
`Plot[{-4 (x - 1) + 13, (x - 1)/4 + 13}, {x, -1, 3}, 
 AspectRatio -> Automatic]`

Answer (score 2):

In your case you'll want a square grid:

```
I1 = Plot[{-4 (x - 1) + 13}, {x, -1, 3}, AspectRatio -> Automatic]
I2 = Plot[{(x - 1)/4 + 13}, {x, -1, 3}]
Show[I1, I2]
```